# javascript auto submit to form without name (tumblr)

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I want to make auto submit code in JavaScript for Tumblr but the problem is that the form doesnt have name. I cant edit html I will put code in Tampermonkey in Chrome (same as Greasmonkey in Firefox).

```
<form id="post_form" style="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="active" data-post-type="photo">

<div>some photo</div>

<button class="chrome blue txt " type="submit">Reblog post</button>

</form>
```

I tried a number of ways but nothing works.

Comment: You don't need a name. You have an id.  `document.getElementById('post_form').submit()`

Comment: If its not your site, where are you going to insert the JS code? In the browser title bar?

Comment: in greasmonkey or tampermonkey, sorry I forgot to write that.

Comment: Ok, in that case `document.getElementById('post_form').submit()` should work - see comment form MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Unfortunately when I put this in console I got popup: You have unsaved post, do you want leave site? when I press leave site is reloading but nothing happend.

Comment: This worked for me: `document.getElementById('post_form').getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()`